# How to convert timestamp columns to timestamp formats from string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe:

```
   date1          date2
2021-11-02    2021-11-02
2021-11-02    2021-11-03
2021-11-02    2021-11-07
```

I want to add column "day" which is equal to difference between date2 and date1. I do `df["day"] = df["date2"] - df["date1"]` But brings error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'` How to fix it? How to turn them into timestamp?

Comment: I did not understand your question correctly. But if the only problem is that the strings can not be subtracted, convert them to integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['day'] = (df['date2'].astype('datetime64') - df['date1'].
             astype('datetime64')).dt.days
print(df)
```

```
        date1       date2  day
0  2021-11-02  2021-11-02    0
1  2021-11-02  2021-11-03    1
2  2021-11-02  2021-11-07    5
```